# UIDatePicker and UIPickerView not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview, uidatepicker

However I set up a `UIDatePicker` or a `UIPickerView` inside an existing project, they don't work, they don't react to touch. I've even moved the whole `UIViewController` to another project and it works in that project.

Any clue would be really appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I found it was a category on `UITableViewCell` what broke the `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: What have you tried? Have added them programmatically or through Storyboard / xib? Your question does not provide any details.

Comment: I have tried both programmatically and through xib. Thing is, it does work in another project...

Comment: What is your question exactly? What have you done that doesn't work? What's the code of your `UIViewController`?

Comment: @UditS I found the problem. Thanks for trying to help me.